# Why does AES_ENCRYPT not work on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tested AES_ENCRYPT(str,key) on phpmyadmin on XAMPP and it work. but when attempting to do the same on Microsoft SQL server i get an error of 'AES_ENCRYPT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Do i need to install AES_ENCRYPT as a function.
I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `AES_ENCRYPT` is not a function in TSQL. You need to use SQL server equivalent encryption. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/data-encryption-in-sql-server)

Comment: Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL. MySQL and T-SQL are not the same. If you are migrating from one RDBMS to another, you will need to change some (or large amount) of code.

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the replies, Changing code.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`ENCRYPTBYKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql) on SQL Server, e.g.:

```sql
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
  
-- Create a column in which to store the encrypted data.  
ALTER TABLE HumanResources.Employee  
    ADD EncryptedNationalIDNumber varbinary(128);   
GO  
  
-- Open the symmetric key with which to encrypt the data.  
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;  
  
-- Encrypt the value in column NationalIDNumber with symmetric key  
-- SSN_Key_01. Save the result in column EncryptedNationalIDNumber.  
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee  
SET EncryptedNationalIDNumber  
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), NationalIDNumber);  
GO
```

The encryption algorithm used is dependent on the provided key so you need to use [`CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql) to create a key for use with the `AES-256` algorithm, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY JanainaKey09
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Shipping04;
```